# Using pandoc and pandoc-citeproc with Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert, pypandoc

I am developing an infrastructure where developers can document their verification tests using Jupyter notebooks. One part of the infrastructure will be a python script that can convert their `.ipynb` files to `.html` files to provide public-facing documentation of their tests.

Using the `nbconvert` module does most of what I want, but I would like to allow citations and references in the final HTML file. I can use `pypandoc` to generate HTML text that converts the citations to proper inlined syntax and adds a **References** section:

```
from urllib import urlopen
import nbformat
import pypandoc
from nbconvert import MarkdownExporter

response = urlopen('SimpleExample.ipynb').read().decode()
notebook = nbformat.reads(response, as_version=4)
exporter = MarkdownExporter()
(body, resources) = exporter.from_notebook_node(notebook)

filters = ['pandoc-citeproc']
extra_args = ['--bibliography="ref.bib"',
              '--reference-links',
              '--csl=MWR.csl']
new_body = pypandoc.convert_text(body,
                                 'html',
                                 'md',
                                 filters=filters,
                                 extra_args=extra_args)
```

The problem is that this generated HTML loses all of the considerable formatting and other capabilities provided by `nbconvert.HTMLExporter`.

My question is, is there a straightforward way to merge the results of `nbconvert.HTMLExporter` and `pypandoc.convert_text()` such that I get mostly the former, with inline citations and a **Reference** section added from the latter?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that this necessarily counts as "straightforward" but I was able to come up with a solution. It involves writing a class that inherits from `nbconvert.preprocessors.Preprocessor` and implements the `preprocess(self, nb, resources)` method. Here is what `preprocess()` does:

1. Loop over every cell in the notebook and store a `set` of citation keys (these are of the form `[@bibtex_key]`
2. Create a short body of text consisting of only these citation keys, each separated by `'\n\n'`
3. Use the `pandoc` conversion above to generate HTML text from this short body of text. If `num_cite` is the number of citations, the first `num_cite` lines of the generated text will be the inline versions of the citations (e.g. '(Author, Year)'); the remaining lines will be the content of the references section.
4. Go back through each cell and substitute the inline text of each citation for its key.
5. Add a cell to the notebook with `## References`
6. Add a cell to the notebook with the content of the references section

Now, when an `HTMLExporter`, using this `Preprocessor`, converts a notebook, the results will have inline citations, a reference section, and all of the formatting you expect from the `HTMLExporter`.